# Default algorithm for scalar multiplication of elliptic curve points by the MIRACL Library

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, finite-field

What is the default algorithm used by the MIRACL-Library [1] for elliptic curve cryptography systems to perform scalar-point multiplication with curves of Weierstrass form satisfying the equation : $y^2 \equiv x^3 + a\cdot x + b \pmod p$ defined over a prime Field $\mathbb{F}_p$ ?

I can't find any satisfying information about the used method, the point representation and the costs for the formulars.

---

[1] https://github.com/CertiVox/MIRACL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends your compilation options but the function **ecurve_mult** in [MIRACL/source/mrcurve.c](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/blob/deab194e1ae7156eb25a2d65ff539cd2d4afb2d2/source/mrcurve.c) seems to use the [w-ary non-adjacent form (wNAF) method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#w-ary_non-adjacent_form_.28wNAF.29_method).